# how to save dynamic value to the room entity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to store a custom data type in a single database column depending on the user chosen. How can I store the data into room database?

```
@Entity
data class Choice (
    @PrimaryKey 
    var id: Int = 0, 
    var option: Any? = null
)
```

I want to store the data on option. Depending on the user selection it could store any one custom data class type out of 50 different options. How can I achieve it?

Comment: There is no easy way. Make all of the data classes inherit some other class and create type converters for it. But even so in type converters you'll have to manually check type and implement toString/fromString logic for every option. I wouldsuggest you to refactor your current solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, you need your app to store a custom data type in a single database column. You support custom types by providing type converters, which are methods that tell Room how to convert custom types to and from known types that Room can persist. You identify type converters by using the @TypeConverter annotation.

```
class Converters {
@TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
  return value?.let { Date(it) }
}

@TypeConverter
fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
  return date?.time?.toLong()
}
}
```

For further understanding you can visit android official documentation: [Android Room Complex Data Types](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)